# Each statement cannot iterate through current_user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I'm trying to list a todo list of the user that is currently logged in. I'm using devise as my authentication gem.

The code goes like:

```
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @todo_items = Todo.all.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
      @new_todo = Todo.new
    else 
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

but when i run this i get this error

```
undefined method `each' for #<Todo:0x38b8d68>
```

my iteration statement is:

```
<div class="well">
  <% @todo_items.each do |t| %> **#error in this line.**
    <li> <%= t.todo_item %> </li>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
i've also tried

```
@todo_items = Todo.all.find_by_user_id(params[:current_user.id])
```

i still get the same error.
I'm fairly new at this and not using any tutorials as of now for this so please try to explain your answer from a newbie point of view. thanks

Comment: Basically spickermann answers it and you can also refactor this because you don't the if condition - devise got a helper for that. It's called  before_filter :authenticate_user!.

Comment: i understood the part where i'm using find by. i used where instead and works like a charm. and yea i read about the before filer and used it instead of "if". thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running this

```
Todo.all.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

First,

```
Todo.all will return all the user records
```

and you applied find_by_user_id on Todo.all, as we know find_by method returns single record

Obviously,

```
Todo.all.find_by_user_id
```

will return single record, because you are finding single user from all users.

And your are trying to iterate through single record that is causing error.

```
<% @todo_items.each do |t| %> **#error in this line.**
 <li> <%= t.todo_item %> </li>
<% end %>
```

Try in a different way,

```
Todo.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    (or)
Todo.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    (or)
Todo.all(:where => "user_id => #{current_user.id}")
```

any of above will work.

Comment: i tried all but is there any diff in those when deployed online. like speed and response times?...which one is preferred?..thanks for the reply anyway...chose your answer...thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. Model.find(:all) or model.find_by() methods are deprecated from rails rails 4 and later versions, If you are going to use latest versions from rails 4 you have to go with model.where(). You can get detailed view about this here http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Answer (score 0):

`find_by_user_id(...)` is the same like `where(:user_id => ...).first` and returns only one item. You probably want to use:

```
Todo.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

what returns an array (and responds to `each`). Or even better: If our user model has a `has_many` association to `todos` just write:

```
current_user.todos
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will look like something

```
 class TodosController < ApplicationController
   def index
    if user_signed_in?
     @todo_items = Todo.where(user_id: current_user.id)
     @new_todo = Todo.new
    else 
     redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
   end
  end
```

and then

```
  <div class="well">
   <% @todo_items.each do |t| %> **#error in this line.**
   <li> <%= t.todo_item %> </li>
   <% end %>
  </div>
```